# Regular expression in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

Following code is not working. It is not including later text in output:

```
 (regexp-match #rx"[*A-Za-z0-9_ ]+" "this is a test | > < ? abcd ")
'("this is a test ")
```

I want abcd also to come. Basically I want these characters to be allowed and all other remvoved:  A-Za-z0-9_ and space (' ').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`regexp-match`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/regexp.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._regexp-match%29%29) returns the first match; [`regexp-match*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/regexp.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._regexp-match*%29%29) returns all matches.

```
> (regexp-match #rx"[*A-Za-z0-9_ ]+" "this is a test | > < ? abcd ")
(list "this is a test ")
> (regexp-match* #rx"[*A-Za-z0-9_ ]+" "this is a test | > < ? abcd ")
(list "this is a test " " " " " " " " abcd ")
```

To remove those characters, you can join all of the matches together with `string-append*`

```
> (string-append* (regexp-match* #rx"[*A-Za-z0-9_ ]+" "this is a test | > < ? abcd "))
"this is a test     abcd "
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`regexp-replace*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/regexp.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._regexp-replace%2A%29%29) with a negated character class.

```
(regexp-replace* #rx"[^*A-Za-z0-9_ ]" "this is a test | > < ? abcd " "")
=> "this is a test     abcd "
```

By the way, the `*` inside the character class will match a literal `*`.

```
(regexp-replace* #rx"[^*A-Za-z0-9_ ]" "******" "")
=> "******"
```